# Расстановка знаков препинания внутри прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

> Александр Розенбаум: «Люди помнят меня доктором — это очень приятно,
>   обычно врачей скорой не запоминают».

В этом предложении правильно расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это лучший вариант: **Люди помнят меня доктором — это очень приятно, обычно врачей скорой не запоминают.**

А есть еще варианты, причем четыре, а не три,  и все правильные? Неужели такое возможно? Кроме того,  хотелось бы узнать, как расставлять **акценты** и что это такое.

Из словаря: **АКЦЕНТ**. 1. Лингв. Ударение в слове. // Знак ударения. Расставить в тексте акценты. Неправильно поставлен а.

Д**а, словарь нам мало помог.** Наверное, чтобы расставлять акценты, нужно хорошее внутреннее чувство языка. Или можно обойтись без него?

**Итак, как решаются подобные задачи.**

Это БСП, состоящее из трех предложений, и мы знаем, что смысловые отношения в БСП определяются интонацией и, соответственно, знаками препинания. А здесь к тому же **не два, а три предложени**я, причем явно не однородные, а взаимосвязанные по смыслу. так что задача стоит сложная.

Основные знаки в БСП — это запятые, тире и двоеточие. Правила регулируют их выбор, но не всегда справляются даже с двумя предложениями, а здесь целых три.

Ну а  теперь, после небольшого вступления, рассмотрим варианты.

Вариант 1. **Люди помнят меня доктором, это очень приятно, обычно врачей скорой не запоминают**.

Ставим только запятые. Вариант самый простой, **а какие в нем акценты?** Можно сказать, что никаких. По смыслу второе и третье предложение просто распространяют тему первого. По интонации это **монотонное прочтение** с понижением голоса в конце каждой части, как будто мы читаем три отдельных предложения, но с уменьшенной паузой между ними. **Да, вариант не из лучших, ведь непонятно, как связаны предложения, что хотел сказать автор.**

Что делать? Надо разделить предложение на блоки: 1 и 2 + 3 или 1 + 2 и 3.

Вариант 2 (1 + 2 и 3). **Люди помнят меня доктором, это очень приятно: обычно врачей скорой не запоминают.**

Взаимообусловленность  предложений обозначена двоеточием. Это уже неплохо, но только на письме, потому что **интонацию подобрать трудно**. Пара (1 + 2) опять же читается монотонно, а это понижение голоса в конце первой части и маленькая пауза, потом опять же понижение голоса и большая пауза, обозначенная двоеточием. **Как-то сложно и невыразительно.**

Вариант 3 (1 и 2 + 3). **Люди помнят меня доктором — это очень приятно, обычно врачей скорой не запоминают.**

Это самый лучший вариант, здесь обособленная конструкция имеет **присоединительный** характер. Первая часть — основная по смыслу, вторая (2 + 3) — комментарий к ней. **Вот такие (очень неплохие) акценты**

А как же вариант 4 с двоеточием и тире: **Люди помнят меня доктором — это очень приятно: обычно врачей скорой не запоминают.**

**Этот вариант совсем нехорош.** Тире, очевидно, присоединительное, это тот же комментарий, но причинно-следственные отношения не письме выражаются именно в нем, а как все это читать — неизвестно. **Два сильных знака (каждый со своей интонацией) на очень маленький объём текста.**

Comment: В журнал пошел заголовок под № 3, как Вы и советовали. Большое спасибо за подробный разбор. Предложение оказалось непростым.

Answer (score 2):

Да, правильно, но возможны варианты, зависит от того, как расставить акценты:

«*Люди помнят меня доктором,  это очень приятно: обычно врачей скорой не запоминают».*

*«Люди помнят меня доктором — это очень приятно: обычно врачей скорой не запоминают».*

*«Люди помнят меня доктором, это очень приятно, обычно врачей скорой не запоминают».*